# Streamsets Error - Bad File Descriptor

Tags: java, macos, jdbc, streamsets

I was attempting to use Streamsets to query an Oracle database and publish the data into Kafka.  I downloaded Streamsets' tarball on my Mac and unzipped it into my home directory.  Running `$HOME/streamsets-datacollector-2.1.0.2/bin/streamsets dc` started up on my first try, then I followed the instructions [here](https://groups.google.com/a/streamsets.com/d/msg/sdc-user/nWKg_8ll4-Q/e2CCn51fDQAJ) to add the jdbc driver, then the instructions [here](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Origins/JDBCConsumer.html#concept_qhf_hjr_bs) to configure my streamsets job.  However, I got an error: `JDBC_00 - Cannot connect to specified database: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_06 - Failed to initialize connection pool: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Bad file descriptor`.

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question, but I wanted to document my problem and solution for future-people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wound up having something to do with the limit on the number of files a process can have open. When I ran `ulimit -n` on the laptop, it showed `4864`, then I set it to `10,000` via `ulimit -n 10000`, restarted the streamsets server, and it worked! If I need to keep running this, I will find a more procedural way of setting the ulimit for this process to work around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you definitely want need increase ulimit -n.  To permanently change for all users in Ubuntu try the following:

```
echo "* soft nofile 60000" > /etc/security/limits.d/*_limits.conf && echo "* hard nofile 60000" >> /etc/security/limits.d/*_limits.conf
```

substitute 60000 with whatever number you want.  I've never had a problem in streamsets using 60k.  you should be able to do something similar in bsd.